# Convert string to int unsigned

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

I am creating a procedure that will allow me to auto increment a primary key
my way.

They key has a structure of M or V followed by a number.

The key for the table is defined as `varchar(100)`.

The procedure gets the largest existing key, strips the first character and the next step is to add 10 to the number and make a new key using CONCAT.

How do I convert the number string I created with SUBSTRING to a numeric (`int`) unsigned so I can add 10 to it?

SUBSTRING returns the numeric string to a field `mfg_ven_num` declared as 
`varchar(100)`.

Do I need something like `cast(mfg_ven_num as int)`? if I do not comment it out I get a syntax error.

This is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`pete`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `gen_mfg_ven_id`(out mv_id varchar(100), IN mv_flag char(1))
BEGIN
declare cnt int default 1000;
declare id_auto int default 0;
declare mfg_ven_name varchar(100) default "Manufacture not Assigned";
declare last_id VARCHAR (100) default NULL;
declare mfg_ven_num varchar(100) default null;

select count(*) from mfg_ven into cnt;

  if cnt = 3 then

      --default Wanufacture

       insert into mfg_ven (mfg_ven_id, mv_flag,id_auto,mfg_ven_name)
       values ('M1099', 'N', 1000, ame);

       -- default Vendor

       insert into mfg_ven (mfg_ven_id, mv_flag,id_auto,mfg_ven_name)
       values ('V1000', 'v', 1000, 'Vendor Not Assigned');

  else
       select max(mfg_ven_id) from mfg_ven into last_id;
       SELECT SUBSTRING(last_id, 2) into mfg_ven_num; # strip first character
       #cast(mfg_ven_num as int unsigned); # Change frow string to numeric
       set mfg_ven_num = mfg_ven_num + 10;

       select concat(mv_flag, mfg_ven_num) into mv_id;

end if;

END
```

Comment: I've replaced your screenshot with the text of your code. Please post text instead of pictures of text, thank you.

Comment: As for your question, does your code work for you without using the CAST function? If not, could you elaborate on the scenario that produces the wrong result? As far as I can see, the part that does the increment should work as expected, and if you just would like someone to explain why/how it works without CAST, I think that should be clarified in your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You have a big issue here: it is the usage of MAX function against a string field. The results won't be as expected. For example, mv10000 would be smaller than mv2 when comparing strings. My suggestion is to use another field for the incremented number, then concat it with 'mv' to generate the PK.

Comment: I decided to add a numeric value as a separate field and update it each time a new id is added and updating it.

Comment: The problem with my origional logic is that  the procedure can not do an insert from the same table trigger that called the procedure. I had to re-think my logic and not do an insert in the procedure. Thanks